# Should inline validation check empty fields if user only tab the field but do nothing and skip to next field?

Tags: forms

I have a form in mobile apps where I need to use inline validation but it's kind of annoying for users if it prompts error message (this field is required) even they don't key in anything inside the field. (just clicking the field and move to next field). The behavior for the form should be:

1. required field message appeared after clicking submit button.
2. inline validation only happen when user key in something in the
   field(this include invalid format etc wrong email format).

Is this good in UX point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is required, the form should not be able to be saved/submitted/etc. until a valid entry has been made in that field.

### However, I would not use an error message to indicate this. I recommend using a "required field" indicator like a red asterisk on the field title, and to only use in-line validation if the user attempts to go forward without addressing the required field.

Example:[image]